# PHP class or method to decrypt the DES Encryption

Tags: php, encryption, des

Are DES Encryption called "One Way Encryption" or "two way Encryption" ?
Are there a PHP class or method to decrypt the DES Encryption ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The php [crypt](https://www.php.net/crypt) function is a one-way hashing function, if you want to be able to decrypt, take a look at the [mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) extension which supports [a range of algorithms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php)

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that there are (and have always been) questions surrounding the [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) algorithm. It's been widely in use for a long time, but since it was originally specified with only a 56 bit key, it's questionable whether it's secure enough for any important uses at this point. Triple DES is generally better, but there are some known theoretical attacks. If you have a choice of cipher, you might want to look at [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) instead.

Answer (score 2):

DES can be reversed, so it's a two-way encryption (if you meant that).

DES is a pretty well known encryption standard so it should be available in PHP too.

Answer (score 2):

**One-way encryption** is a secure form of *hashing*: the plaintext is changed into an apparently random sequence of data, often of fixed length, in such a way that the original plaintext (theoretically) cannot be retrieved without a brute-force effort.

**Two-way encryption**, or **reversible encryption** is what we normally mean by the term *encryption*: the plaintext is transformed into apparently random data, but in a way that relies on a "key" that allows the original plaintext to be retrieved.

DES is a form of reversible encryption that is relatively weak by today's standards, as it relies on a 56-bit key (14 hex characters).  It has been superseded by 3DES, or triple-DES, which is essentially the same algorithm with a longer key.

You don't mention your application, but if you need only to *compare* the data and not *retrieve* it, hashing is considered more secure.  For example, you can store hashed passwords; then, when a user authenticates, perform the same hash on the entered text and compare it with the stored hashed value.  If they match, the correct password was entered.

A significant advantage to hashing is that you don't need to store a decryption key.

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with the "one way encryption" or "two way encryption" terms. There is a term "one time password" (totally irrelevant for DES), and there are "symmetric" and "assymetric" encryption algorithms, meaning whether the same key is used for encryption and decryption (symmetric) or a set of two different keys is used one for encryption and another for decryption (assymetric). DES is a symmetric algorithm. As for PHP, crypt() since to be doing the job:

https://www.php.net/crypt

Comment: crypt is a one-way hashing function

Answer (score -1):

I Think you probably mean a one-way function [1]. In cryptography one distinguishes between symmetric and asymmetric cryptography. Symmetric cryptography uses the same key to encrypt and decrypt (DES is symmetric). Asymmetric Cryptography is used for key exchange and a public key is used to encrypt the message, while the private key is used to decrypt it. An example of Asymmetric Cryptography is AES [2]. Asymmetric cryptography uses one way functions.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function
[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES

Comment: You are mistaken about AES. It is a symmetrical key based algorithm. The rest of your answer is imprecise as well.

Comment: Sorry I did too much things at the same time. I meant of course RSA and not AES.